Intel C compiler in conda
How does one install intel compilers into a conda environment. Following this I did:
conda install intel::icc_rt

But this tells me:
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - intel
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 24.3.0
    latest version: 24.4.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda



# All requested packages already installed.

On the other hand icc --version says command not found. Intel's own conda page hasn't been much help either.

nowhere in your linked page does it say icc_rt. Or even icc or C-compiler. Is that the right link?

btw, this is the latest version of the link you provided: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-windows/2024-1/conda.html (which still doesnt mention icc_rt unless I am blind)

icc_rt is the runtime libraries, not the compiler.
